# Does yum have an equivalent to /var/log/apt/term.log?

Tags: logs, yum, gitlab

I just updated a package on a Centos host and was wondering if there is something like `/var/log/apt/term.log` on RHEL derivates I don't know about? I know about `yum history`, but in this case having full terminal log would be great because the package I updated printed so many lines that I'm missing a good chunk of lines between start (I copied these already) and completion. I've been using tmux already and I didn't expect gitlab omnibus installation to print this much to the terminal. :-( Now I want to make sure I have not overlooked anything.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7

```
/var/log/yum.log
```

CentOS 8

```
/var/log/dnf.log
```

They both give detailed information on all of the packages that have been installed and updated via `yum` and/or `dnf`.

`/var/log/yum.log` doesn't give the full terminal output but it gives enough information on what was done (installed, upgraded, erased) for you to know what happened.

`/var/log/dnf.log` does provide the full terminal output.

Comment: I looked at `/var/log/yum.log` and it just contains packages names. `var/log/apt/term.log` on the other side has the full log of the terminal output during installation. If I have a terminal attached to the process and start typing during installation, that gibberish will also be in the log. When packages are installed through unattended updates I could check if there was an error during installation. Sounds clunky, but can be useful.

Comment: @LiveWireBT `/var/log/dnf.log` in CentOS 8 and RHEL 8 gives the terminal output. RHEL 7 only gives the packages that were installed, upgraded, or erased but what else do you need? If it says `installed package.....etc`, then that's clearly what was done. The exact thing that you are looking for in CentOS 7 and RHEL 7 does not exist but the log files supplies enough information for one to know what occurred. What you are looking for does exist in CentOS 8 and RHEL 8. In any event, either the package installed or it didn't. One doesn't need the entire terminal output to know this.